# In matlab, I have 5 sentences all in one array, and I need to count and display the number of characters for each sentence using a for loop

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, for-loop

So my code for this is:

```
my5Sentences={'Windows machines are better than Macs.','The Intel core i7 4770k is a great processor.','My email is xxxxx@drexel.edu','I go to Drexel','I am writing this in MATLAB & and I writing this code for Engr-180'}

for 1:length(my5Sentences)
```

Now, I am not sure what to do inside the for loop to index the sentence and check for the character size.

Answer (score 0):

use the function "size" instead of for loop

Comment: I think for this exercise we are required to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To index, use the {} operator:

```
for i=1:(my5sentences)
    fprintf('length(%s)=%i',my5Sentences{i},length(my5Sentences{i}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you also explain how I would get and display the number of special characters in each sentence?

Comment: I would ask a separate question for that question.

Comment: @user2971806: Editing a question to ask something different when you've already asked a question is bad form. I suggest you accept the answer you have here, and ask an entirely different question, reverting back to your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this website.